# Saving an array of arrays in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am sending an array of data from an ajax POST and trying to save them into my model. What I am getting however are empty arrays. `[ [],[],[] ]`

**edit**

Thanks to the comments below I updated my model and I am now getting the data that I needed.

However, when I add in the user relationship to it, that brings back errors.

I will append that to the end since this is getting quite long

**/edit**

I have it set up to iterate over the data which looks like this originally:

`[{start: 1.17, end: 1.66, id: "region_ovkb6fg"},
{start: 2.19, end: 2.53, id: "region_jereppo"},
{start: 3.07, end: 3.53, id: "region_scpnvmo"}]`

Here's what I'm doing in my controller:

```
public function store ( Request $request)
  {
    if($request->ajax()) {

        $data = $request->all();

        foreach ( $data as $v ) {

          // Region is the name of the Model and is included at the top of the page
          $inserts[] = new Region( array('region_id'=> $v['id'], 'start' => $v['start'], 'end' => $v['end'])); 
        }
    return $inserts;

    // Then I also need to add user_id reference 
   }
 }
```

Running the above foreach loop **without** the Model will return the above array with the correct information.

I have tried using this loop *inside* the `new Region()` method but that is not allowed and returns errors.

I have tried using `new Region()->fill($inserts)` but that also didn't work.

What is happening is that `new Region` is creating an array for this array and the data is no longer visible at the top layer. `new Region(array(array(region_id: "wavesurfer_p567v4", start: 1.88, end: 2.59)))`

`dd($inserts)` **without the model** just the loop:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "region_id" => "wavesurfer_3uc44qg"
    "start" => 2.16
    "end" => 3.09
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "region_id" => "wavesurfer_apr1k9"
    "start" => 3.72
    "end" => 4.46
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "region_id" => "wavesurfer_edihseo"
    "start" => 5.13
    "end" => 6
  ]
]
```

`dd($inserts)` **with** the model, using the code from above:

```
    array:2 [
  0 => Region {#156
    #table: "regions"
    #fillable: array:4 [
      0 => "region_id"
      1 => "start"
      2 => "end"
      3 => "data"
    ]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:3 [
      "region_id" => "wavesurfer_dj3g1g8"
      "start" => 2.54
      "end" => 3.14
    ]
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
    #dates: []
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: false
  }
  1 => Region {#158
    #table: "regions"
    #fillable: array:4 [
      0 => "region_id"
      1 => "start"
      2 => "end"
      3 => "data"
    ]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:3 [
      "region_id" => "wavesurfer_808mkm"
      "start" => 3.68
      "end" => 4.14
    ]
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
    #dates: []
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: false
  }
]
```

---

Saving this table.

I am calling `use Auth;` at the top of my controller and adding this:
`Auth::user()->regions()->save($inserts);` results in this error:

```
ErrorException in HasOneOrMany.php line 165:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/HSAnnotator/app/Http/Controllers/WaveController.php on line 45 and defined
```

My Region Model looks like this:

```
class Region extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['region_id','start', 'end', 'data'];
    public function user ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And User Model like this:

```
    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

  /* user related code for passwords and built in things*/


        public function regions ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Region');
        }
        public function markers ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Marker');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have set the `$fillable` attributes in your model? If you are not sure, please post your model code.

Comment: @lukasgeiter yes I have tried both adding all them individually, and right now I have it set like so: `protected $fillable = ['*'];`
I also added `protected $table = 'regions';` when I wasn't sure if it was identifying the table correctly, which it is.

Comment: Hmm.. Don't know if this could be the problem but you should initialize the array before the loop: `$inserts = array();`

Comment: @lukasgeiter I *did* have that in there, but commented it out when playing around with this to see what it did (because I wasn't sure if doing both that and $inserts[] was causing my nested array problem). It appears to make no difference, but I can add it back in.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `dd($inserts)`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I added that to the original question now

Comment: `$fillable = ['*']` doesn't work. You have to either specify them or set `$guarded = []` to allow all input (former is preferable). Also you currently have `region_id` set as guarded which is a problem too.

Comment: @lukasgeiter wow thanks that fixed that problem. I updated the original question. I can now get the data in the model. However it isn't saving when I add in the user to it. Might be better if I make a new question but for now I added it to this one.

Comment: Try `saveMany($inserts)` instead of `save($inserts)`

Comment: @lukasgeiter That did it! Thank you I've been working on this problem for a long time.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add an answer summarizing the comments shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem where the `fillable` and `guarded` attributes.

While the default value of `guarded` is `['*']` that doesn't work for `fillable` as well. It's best to specify all attributes explicitly:

```
protected $fillable = ['region_id', 'start', 'end'];
```

Besides that `guarded` was `['reqion_id']` which doesn't make a lot of sense. An attribute can't be fillable and guarded since they are the opposite.

---

After those fixes the remaining problem was the usage of `save()`. When saving multiple models `saveMany()` has to be used:

```
Auth::user()->regions()->saveMany($inserts);
```